# Day of week in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to get just the day of the week from a specific date in SQL. 
How can I get the day from that date? Please guide me. 
The date, by the way, is `2015-05-2015`.

Comment: what have your tried so far? mysql <> mssql, which platform are you using? not to mention what does `2015-05-2015` mean? its not a valid date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Day of Week in SQL 2005/2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008) or [Select day of week from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967426/select-day-of-week-from-date), depending on what RDBMS you're using

Comment: this may be the answer you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008

Answer (score 6):

In SQL SERVER day can be calculated this way:

```
select datename(dw,getdate()) --Monday

select datepart(dw,getdate()) --1
```

In addition here[enter link description here](http://www.lazerwire.com/2011/10/sql-day-of-week.html) shown how can you calculate day of a week using `datepart` only by creating userdefined function.

In MYSql you can use [weekday()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php) function

```
SELECT WEEKDAY('2009-05-19'); --1
```

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for!

Comment: That assumes SQL Server, since MySQL doesn't have `datename`

Comment: @Rocketq - the question is both tagged with [mysql] and [sql-server-2008], which causes a problem, because it really should only be tagged with one RDBMS

Comment: @Rocketq - how do you know for sure, even mysql is tagged in the question

Comment: @ughai I have included code suitable for both RDBMS