# Count users who have repeatedly called no sooner than 6 days post first call

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

I have to count how many **repeated** times a user has called within next 7 days (days have to be flexible) or more. 
The query should only consider records with the 7 days earlier than the last date in the table.

My data looks something like this:

```
call_date   user  
2017-05-01  100   
2017-05-01  500   
2017-05-02  200   
2017-05-02  300   
2017-05-03  300   
2017-05-04  100   
2017-05-05  400   
2017-05-06  500   
2017-05-07  600   
2017-05-08  200   
2017-05-09  700   
2017-05-10  500   
2017-05-11  400   
2017-05-12  300   
2017-05-13  100   
2017-05-14  200
```

The desired output of the query is:

```
call_date   user count
2017-05-01  100  2  
2017-05-01  500  2  
2017-05-02  200  2  
2017-05-02  300  2  
2017-05-03  300  1  
2017-05-04  100  1  
2017-05-05  400  2 
2017-05-06  500  2 
2017-05-07  600  1
```

Explanation:

- While listing the date the first contact should be considered (`user` 100 called on `2017-05-01`, `2017-05-04` and `2017-05-13`) but only `2017-05-01` displayed
- For `user` 100, only records **within 7 days** should be considered hence `count` of `user` 100 becomes **2** (`2017-05-01` and `2017-05-04`; **excluding** `2017-05-13` since falls out of range) for `call_date` `2017-05-01`
- No records after `2017-05-07` are considered because it is the date which is 7 days earlier than the max date i.e. `2017-05-14`

This query has to run on 25+ million records hence an optimized query would be added advantage.

I am quite unsure as to how to nail down this problem; a detailed explanation with the query would be much appreciated.

Comment: A detailed explanation of your desired output would be much appreciated. Apart from using `rand()`, your counts make no sense at least to me.

Comment: To explain further @Solarflare request: Where does the count of 2 for user 100 and call_date 5/1/2017 come from? Where does the count of 0 for user 500 and call_date 5/1/2016 come from? ... and so on.

Comment: Check if any of *[these](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8bed2b735683dbdfc82f2a0960ffd14a)* is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: @Solarflare I have added the explanation.

Comment: @joanolo. Can you please add your query as an answer so that I can accept. Thank you.

Comment: Well, with correct counts, the counts feel less random now. While I am still not sure how "While listing the date the first contact should be considered (user 100 called on 2017-05-01, 2017-05-04 and 2017-05-13) but only 2017-05-01 displayed" fits with listing `100` again for `2017-05-04` in your desired result, if the desired result is now actually what you are looking for, you can use the code in @joanolo 's fiddle (especially the subquery `count_next_7_days`), which gives you exactly your desired result. (Otherwise please provide a correct desired output).

Comment: There you have it... Now it is consistent with the added explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is your table definition (I've changed user to user_id to avoid clashing with a reserved keyword):

```
CREATE TABLE calls
(
    call_date date NOT NULL, 
    user_id integer NOT NULL
    /* no primary key. There *can* be duplicate rows, that could be
       changed if call_date were instead call_datetime. Then:
       PRIMARY KEY (user_id, call_datetime)
       Assumed user's cannot make simultaneous calls, nor any faster than
       the datetime resolution.
    */ 
)
;
-- These indexes will help `using index` query plans.
CREATE INDEX idx_calls_user_id_call_date ON calls(user_id, call_date) ;
CREATE INDEX idx_calls_call_date_user_id ON calls(call_date, user_id) ;
```

... and that we import your data. We can then query the database with:

```
SELECT
    call_date, user_id, 
    -- Count of the number of calls on `call_date` for `user_id`
    count(call_date) AS count_on_date,
    -- Count of the number of calls between `call_date` and the next 6 days (including both)
    (SELECT count(call_date) FROM calls c1 WHERE c1.user_id = c.user_id AND c1.call_date BETWEEN c.call_date AND c.call_date + interval 6 day) AS count_next_7_days
FROM
    calls c
    -- The next JOIN is used to retrieve the `reference date`, and do it only once.
    -- This will allow to take into account only dates from (2017-05-14 - 13 day) = 2017-05-01 and (2017-05-14 - 7 day) = 2017-05-07
    JOIN (SELECT max(call_date) AS ref_date FROM calls) AS d ON c.call_date BETWEEN ref_date - interval 13 day AND ref_date - interval 7 day
GROUP BY
    call_date, user_id
ORDER BY
    call_date, user_id ;
```

This query will return:

```
call_date  | user_id | count_on_date | count_next_7_days
:--------- | ------: | ------------: | ----------------:
2017-05-01 |     100 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-01 |     500 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-02 |     200 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-02 |     300 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-03 |     300 |             1 |                 1
2017-05-04 |     100 |             1 |                 1
2017-05-05 |     400 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-06 |     500 |             1 |                 2
2017-05-07 |     600 |             1 |                 1
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0ec26e8bf6d9de656a3aa19f4f7936d0)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `DAYOFWEEK()` function? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967426/select-day-of-week-from-date) should be helpful.

Comment: I have taken 7 days just for describing the problem, it can be any number of days.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, and as such may be reviewed in the future and deleted. If you believe the question is a duplicate of another question, then a comment under the question would be better. Since you cannot do that until you have 50 rep, it would be better to hold off until you can.